# How to $project based condition in a Mongo aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I need to execute an aggregation query having this first `$match` stage in the pipeline:

```
match_stage = {
    '$match': {
        'path': {'$in': locations},
        'date': {
            '$or': {
                [
                    {'$gte': range_a_start, '$lte': range_a_end},
                    {'$gte': range_b_start, '$lte': range_b_end},
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I need to match documents into two date ranges and do some date based aggregations based on a `ISODate` field, however I need to perform a `$project` afterwards and I should identify if a document comes from either a match to `range_a` or `range_b`.

I'm not sure how I should achieve this. I've seen there's `$bucket` operator but I've got not much luck so far.

Comment: May be $facet will work for you based on your use case. Something like `match_stage_1 = {
    '$match': {
        'path': {'$in': locations},
        'date':  {'$gte': range_a_start, '$lte': range_a_end}
        }
    }` & `match_stage_2 = {
'$match': {
    'path': {'$in': locations},
    'date':  {'$gte': range_b_start, '$lte': range_b_end}
    }
}` with `db.col.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "first_range":[match_stage_1]
      "second_range": [match_stage_2] 
    }
  }
])`.

Comment: You can also date range comparison directly in the `$project` stage too. May be you can provide some more details and we can come up with appropriate aggregation stages.

Comment: @Veeram which is supposed to be best performance/easy to mantain? Can you provide some examples using `range_a` and `range_b` variables?

Comment: Or any details you may need :)

Answer (score 1):

Further to Veeram's suggestion to use the project stage:

```
// Project some fields to tell us which range.
isInFirstRange: { $cond: { if: {$and:[{'$gte': ["$date", range_a_start]},{'$lte': ["$date", range_a_end]}]}, then: true, else: false } }

isInSecondRange: { $cond: { if: {$and:[{'$gte': ["$date", range_b_start]},{'$lte': ["$date", range_b_end]}]}, then: true, else: false } }
```

Something along these lines...

Edit:  projection is where you want to create "virtual" fields which have values based on real fields and/or formulas, etc.  For example, if you have a circle with a radius of 3, you can save only the radius to the DB and "project" its area as pi * 9.  Area is not saved in the DB.  It is projected during the projections stage.  Read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project).

Comment: Can you extend more on this question?

Comment: Just to be clear, I am projecting fields isInFirstRange and isInSecondRange.  They are either true or false, depending on if the condition is met.  After the aggregation returns all your records, you can query a virtual (projected) field the same as any other field.  if (mydoc.isInFirstRange) {do something;}